# generic acceleration level constraints for kinematic trajectory optimization

Tags: python, robotics, drake, kinematics

I am using drakes [kinematic trajectory optimization](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1planning_1_1trajectory__optimization_1_1_kinematic_trajectory_optimization.html) class via the python bindings and want to add acceleration constraints. I see that for [position](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/b0a9ee53b0f025b6251cc4bb00618b3df7caaeec/planning/trajectory_optimization/kinematic_trajectory_optimization.cc#L256) and [velocity](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/b0a9ee53b0f025b6251cc4bb00618b3df7caaeec/planning/trajectory_optimization/kinematic_trajectory_optimization.cc#L290) constraints there are functions and [wrappers](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/b0a9ee53b0f025b6251cc4bb00618b3df7caaeec/planning/trajectory_optimization/kinematic_trajectory_optimization.cc#L92) that allow to add generic constraints (e.g. allowing to use MultibodyPlant) to the problem, but there is no such option for generic acceleration level constraints. In particular I am interested in limiting the spatial ee-acceleration in specific axes.

Now my questions:

- is there some technical reason for there not being a method to add acceleration constraints or is it just something nobody found useful so far?
- If I were to implement wrappers and functions that would allow me to do so, could I do this in python or is this not possible due to some things not being exposed to the python API? If it is possible, could you briefly sketch out, how one would go about this?
- Is it possible to add a moving frame to the multibody plant that always coincides with the endeffector acceleration vector and add this to the trajopt via an `OrientationConstraint` and `AddPathPositionConstraint` ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answer and for this awesome framework! :)